# Specify the port precisely for a webservice in Web.config

Tags: web-services, client, service

I want to precisely set the port for a .NET 3.5 web service using the client services api

I have been trying to get this to work using
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195.aspx to no avail  I have my domain mydomain .com / Appservices where is Appservices is an app root.

I can login to my web site using the login page but the login when the app is running does not autheticate.  But 2 local webservers start running the main website and the webservice that is a directory off of root the aforementioned AppServices.

What are the troubleshooting techniques here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the port you want to use, already in use? (For example, 110 - POP3).
Is the port accessible through the firewall? [Start->Control Panel->Windows Firewall : Exceptions]
Have you tried setting the port number in IIS? [In properties-> configuration]